# Why does store() function in Anylogic throw an error when calling it to store an agent in a cell?

Tags: java, anylogic

I'm trying to create and store agents of type Agent1 in my `storage` from MHL using codes:

```
Agent1 a = new Agent1();
StorageCell cell = storage.getRandomFreeCell();
cell.store(a);
```

It seems to be correct and can be compiled. The first two lines can be executed. But the third didn't work and threw an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.time(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ExtEntityImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ExtEntityImpl$1.a(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.ExtEntityImpl$1.create(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.c(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.c(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.ExtAgentWithSpatialMetricsDelegate.e(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.ExtEntityDelegate.getColor(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.getColor(Unknown Source)
```

I tried another way of just using `store()` for the `storage`.

```
Agent1 a = new Agent1();
storage.store(a);
```

But the same error occurred too.

Answer (score 2):

OK minutes after I found a solution... The problem may be that the created agent isn't in the flowchart at the moment, so I have to "put" it in the flowcharts using an `enter` block and the codes following:

```
Agent1 a = new Agent1();
enter.take(a);
StorageCell cell = storage.getRandomFreeCell();
cell.store(a);
```

After that, the agent can be stored in the storage.